# Google static image on iphone

Tags: jquery, iphone, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile to develop an app where i want to show  a static google map image. The code I am using is

```
img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=59.33669144545403, 18.062896728515625&zoom=11&size=400x400&maptype=roadmap
&markers=color:red%7Clabel:S%7C59.33669144545403, 18.062896728515625&sensor=false"
```

When on the computer (in Dreamweaver) the map image shows fine and excellent but when I transfer the app to my iPhone the map image is not shown. 
Does anyone know if I need to do anything more in order to show the map on my iPhone?

Comment: You should give code showing how you're using this on your iPhone. You might also get rid of the spaces in the URL, and set sensor to "true".

Comment: Poster doesn't state they use a sensor.

Answer (score 1):

YOu should try this
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/tutorial-iphone.html#HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try this (You will need to substitute the code in bold to your own location):

```
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=72+West+52nd,NY&zoom=14&size=200x200&sensor=false&markers=72+West+52nd,NY"/>
```

The output will look like this:

[image]